# Access label controls have different properties listed - how can I resolve this?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a problem I believe is related to [this problem](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2003/10/access_cleartyp.html). I have many label controls. Some of them become "weird" and start exhibiting a weird "extra bold" display:

[image]

These labels have the same formatting but obviously have different visual representations.

After looking into the properties for both labels, I noticed something quite strange: they have *different* properties. The broken label properties section actually is not showing the HyperLink properties nor the on-event actions.

[image]

In fact, the "Events" properties sheet is actually empty when I go view it.
[image]

I am quite confused what is going on here. I would like a way to fix these controls, preferably using VBA so I can add a programmatic fix to update all the broken labels.

Much to my surprise, the following code works:

```
Application.Forms(gMananger_FormName).controls("Label13").HyperlinkAddress=""
```

I was expecting some sort of error since those labels do not show that control.

I have also tried Compact/Repair to no avail. Nor did turning ClearType off in the Access options, as suggested in the link above.

---

I have also written the following code to copy/add a new control but this breaks completely when controls are in tab spaces (it inserts a new line but doesn't delete the row, perhaps I could fix this if I spend more time, I'm concerned about accidentally deleting a ton of my form controls should I do this).

```
Sub testCopyingControl()
    Dim c
    Dim i As Integer, key
    Dim prop As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set prop = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Set c = Application.Forms(gMananger_FormName).Controls("Label3120")


    For i = 0 To c.Properties.count - 1
        prop.Add c.Properties(i).Name, c.Properties(i).value
    Next i

    Dim newC As Label
    Set newC = CreateControl(gMananger_FormName, acLabel)

    DeleteControl gMananger_FormName, c.Name

    'there are a fair number of readonly properties unfortunately...
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each key In prop.Keys
        Debug.Print key & vbTab & prop(key)
        newC.Properties(key) = prop(key)
    Next key


End Sub
```

I can also fix this individually by cutting/pasting and moving the label back to its grid location. However this is a lot of work as I have quite a few controls doing this.

- How can I first fix a single label control exhibiting this behavior?
- How can I do this programatically via VBA?

Comment: Have you checked whether or not the different labels belong to another control? There are two types of label. If you move a control and the label moves with it, it belongs to that control. There are programmatic ways to check, also.

Comment: @Remou I was actually trying to check that programmatically but couldn't figure out what property was reflected by that (??).

Comment: The parent of an ordinary label is a form, the parent of an 'owned' label is a control: `?Screen.Activeform.labelx.Parent.Name`

Comment: @Remou ah, that appears to be the case. It looks like this is also read only. It also doesn't appear in the list of properties for each when I iterate through them, either, interestingly (using slight modification of the above).

Comment: Do not forget Watch, it reveals a lot of interesting stuff.